# Is it possible to cast a string type containing a number to a type number?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-inference

I can restrict the input validity to be a `number` but can I translate a `string` containing a `number` to an actual `number` ?

```
type ToNumber <S extends string> = S extends `${number}` 
    ? S                          // Change this ?
    : never

type test = ToNumber <'123'>    // is they're a way to get 123 instead of '123'
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gOQK4FsBGEBOUA8BlKCAD2AgDsATAZyiuEwEsyBzAPigF4oDjTKaABgBIA3mVQZMAXwFQAsACgoyqAH5uKzVu06oAej1QAwgAsAhi2jATDGqsWaAXFDIQAblkWLQkKKTqcsIgSWLgA5ACMAEwAzGHsKgZQtn4mECBhmNBmUADuZiB+cFDMEMBQ0THJZHQQZhRQcABmUJGxYYpAA)

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/mqEErm) you have working example. In current TS version it is possible to do only for numbers in range `0 .. 999`. It all depends on recursion limit.

Comment: thank you ;) Shall I delete the question since it's been previously answered ?

Comment: No need to delete it. It will help other people to find appropriate answer. It is ok to have duplicates as long as they marked as such

Comment: @captain-yossarian do tout think it's possible to come up with a solution to handle negative numbers (bound as well) too ? I wrap my head around it but did came short ...

Comment: AFAIK it is impossible to convert `"-5"` string representation to `5` numerical representation. You can't do such kind of math. It is possible to add and substract, but all these operations are done with help of tuple length. It is impossible to to represent tuple with negative length. However it is possible to validate literals. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/m355kw)